# Some permalinks are not working and show 404

Tags: multisite, permalinks, nginx

I'm using WP 4.2.2 on NginX, with a multisite (subdomain) installation, and I have a strange problem. My site has about 18 posts and all post permalinks worked quite fine until this morning, when two of these links suddenly stopped working and showed a 404 error page.

These things I have already tried:

- Check if title and URL are WP reserved keywords (they aren't)
- Empty browser and server cache, and try again (failed)
- Changed permalink settings to default (worked but I don't want that)
- Edited permalink settings to default, date, category and back to posts name (failed)
- Deactivated all plugins (error is still active)
- Renamed post and changed URL (worked)
- Renamed post and URL, saved changes, undo changes and save again (fail)

I want to know what I have to change so that the broken links work again. I don't want to check every morning to see which links are broken and have to be renamed.

NOTE: I updated translations this morning. I'm not sure if the problem already existed before that, but I think so.

I edited two of my posts and added pictures, moved them in the article and edited them. Suddenly those two posts don't work either.

Comment: Solution:
there were posts and pages with the same name in the trash

Answer (score 1):

we found the solution:

There were deleted Pages and/or Posts with the same title. We removed them and now everythings works!

Comment: Nice solution. FYI you can accept your own answer, to help others with the same problem.